# Cannot resolve symbol "preference"

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am building an Android TV app and want to use

```
LeanbackListPreferenceDialogFragment
```

However, the Studio says "Cannot resolve symbol "preference" on my import string:

```
import android.support.v17.preference.LeanbackListPreferenceDialogFragment;
```

I have the leanback library dependency added in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.0.0'
```

The link to API reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/preference/LeanbackListPreferenceDialogFragment.html

Any hints and help is appreciated.

Eugene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing

`compile 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:25.0.0'`

[See here for more details](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v14-preference)